# In Scala, How to create TypeTag[Map[A,B]], while only TypeTag[A] and TypeTag[B] are available?

Tags: scala, type-erasure

Assuming both type A and B are erased and unknown at run time.

Is there a way to construct TypeTag[Map[A,B]]?

Preferrably using only explicit constructor, as in my real code both A and B are wildcard (it is possible to assign type parameters to 2 functions invoking them but why bother extracting 2 methods when they are only used once).

Thank you for your idea. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Preferrably using only explicit constructor, as in my real code both A and B are wildcard

It isn't completely clear, but do you mean that you have `tagA: TypeTag[_]` and `tagB: TypeTag[_]`? If so, then you can do

```
(tagA, tagB) match {
  case (tagA: TypeTag[a], tagB: TypeTag[b]) =>
    implicit val tagA1 = tagA
    implicit val tagB1 = tagB
    typeTag[Map[a, b]]
}
```

Somewhat ugly and boilerplaty, but I don't think there is a better way currently (and would be happy to learn otherwise).

Comment: Yes, your answer is perfect, I don't know type parameters can be used in case expression like this

Comment: But I also found that your solution won't work in a slightly different case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634849/how-to-case-match-a-type-variable-enclosed-in-a-generic-type